# XCTAssertThrowsSpecific example

Tags: objective-c, xctest

I have an XCTest case with the following code:

```
- (void)testNilInDict
{
    NSMutableDictionary *r = (NSMutableDictionary*) @{@"1": @1, @"2": @2};
    XCTAssertThrowsSpecific([r setObject:nil forKey:@"3"], NSInvalidArgumentException);
}
```

This does not build. Then, I wanted to look for the correct syntax or an example online, but all I found was a list of websites which only repeat what the documentation already states.

```
XCTAssertThrowsSpecific (expression, specificException, format...)
```

Found for instance [here](http://iosunittesting.com/xctest-assertions/), [here](http://rshankar.com/assertions-supported-in-xctest/), [here](https://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/39602/XTCTest-Assertions) and [here](http://appleprogramming.com/blog/2013/12/26/xctest-assertions-documentation/).

My questions are:

1. What is a correct example of the syntax of this particular function?
2. What would be a good website to start looking for these types of
   examples, without finding too much hard core code.

Comment: What's the build error that you're getting?

Comment: Unknown type name 'NSInvalidArgumentException'. I found out that if I change this to NSException, it works. Somehow, NSInvalidArgumentException is not recognized by Xcode and the compiler, even though this is the error that is raised in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSInvalidArgumentException` is the name (i.e. [`-[NSException name]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSException_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSException/name)) of the exception, not the class.

Here is an example of the proper usage of `XCTAssertThrowsSpecific`:

```c
XCTAssertThrowsSpecific([obj methodThatThrowsException], NSException, @"Optional assertion failure description");
```

If you'd like to know when an exception with a specific name (e.g. `NSInvalidArgumentException`) is thrown, use `XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed`:

```c
XCTAssertThrowsSpecificNamed([obj methodThatThrowsException], NSException, NSInvalidArgumentException);
```